# Filtering/Searching Log Files by Date and Error Using Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to search through a log file based on the previous days date and then search for the keyword "ERROR-xxx" for that date. If an error is found, it needs to be copied to a seperate log file. (Not sure if this helps, but previous days entries are always at the end of the file).

I am trying to do this using command-line as it needs to be scripted/automated. Not sure how this can be done in Windows.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: will be very difficult to do in .bat file. you should look into the features, etc in windows powershell to see it that will help. You might want to add a tag for powershell, so you'll have more experienced people looking at this question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#Yesterday) is a good place to find batch files for date manipulation this coupled with the findstr tool specifically:

```
findstr /c "%yesterday%" | findstr /r "ERROR-%xxx%" logfile.log
```

/c matches a literal string (can contain spaces) 
/r lets you parse regular expressions (similar to grep in unix) this should get you to a scripted solution.